# Resize Userform and its Controls with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to resize a userform and its controls with VBA in order to accommodate different size monitors.  Following is the code I am using which is based on Ron DeBruin's code (http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac022.htm).

In essence, the code is designed to scale the userform's size and location together with all of its controls.

The problem is I'm getting an error (shown below) on execution

```
"Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': Method 'Properties' of object '_VBComponent' failed"
```

I tried replacing `.Properties("Top")` with `.Top` and I got the `Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

Mr. DeBruin's code makes since; but I am at a loss as to why it is not working.  Any help would certainly be appreciated.

```
Sub ChangeUserFormAndControlsSize()
    Dim AppUserform As Object
    Dim FormControl As Object
    Dim NameUserform As String
    Dim SizeCoefficient As Single

    SizeCoefficient = wsControls.Range("SizeCoefficient")

    NameUserform = "form_APScheduler"

    Set AppUserform = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(NameUserform)
    With AppUserform
        .Properties("Top") = .Properties("Top") * SizeCoefficient   '*** ERROR OCCURS HERE
        .Properties("Left") = .Properties("Left") * SizeCoefficient
        .Properties("Height") = .Properties("Height") * SizeCoefficient
        .Properties("Width") = .Properties("Width") * SizeCoefficient
    End With

    For Each FormControl In AppUserform.Designer.Controls
        With FormControl
            .Top = .Top * SizeCoefficient
            .Left = .Left * SizeCoefficient
            .Width = .Width * SizeCoefficient
            .Height = .Height * SizeCoefficient

            On Error Resume Next
            .Font.Size = .Font.Size * SizeCoefficient
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next FormControl

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you enabled access to the VBA project object model through the trust centre? This is required to work with the object model.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.  While I am trying to get Mr. DeBruin's code to work, ultimately I want to be able to loop through all the userforms in the workbook in order to scale them all.  Something to the effect of:  For Each AppUserform in Workbook....

Comment: I'm not sure on the issue in which case but will warn that access to the VBA project object model will need to be manually enabled on each computer that the userform will be used on.

Comment: I can run that code without error. If you set a break at With AppUserform and set a watch for AppUserform, what do you see? Is the object OK? Also, is SizeCoefficient  OK at that point?

Comment: I set a watch on AppUserform.  What did I see?  Lot of info there (pardon my ignorance) but one thing that looked interesting was "Name : "form_APScheduler" : String : Module1.ChangeUserFormAndControlsSize".  The name is correct.  Is the object OK? I'm not sure what to look for to answer that.  Is SizeCoefficient OK?  Yes; the variable still had the correct value (.75 in this case).  Question: can this be done another way, i.e., without accessing the VBA project object model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, here is some example code showing how to change the properties at run time, without accessing the VBIDE.VBProject object.  Of course, these changes will not persist.

```
Option Explicit
Sub testForm()
Dim UF As form_APScheduler
Dim FormControl As MSForms.Control
Dim SizeCoefficient As Double

    SizeCoefficient = inputNumber("Scale Factor: ", "Form", 1)
    Set UF = New form_APScheduler
    With UF
        .Top = .Top * SizeCoefficient
        .Left = .Left * SizeCoefficient
        .Width = .Width * SizeCoefficient
        .Height = .Height * SizeCoefficient
    End With
    For Each FormControl In UF.Controls
        With FormControl
            .Top = .Top * SizeCoefficient
            .Left = .Left * SizeCoefficient
            .Width = .Width * SizeCoefficient
            .Height = .Height * SizeCoefficient

            On Error Resume Next
            .Font.Size = .Font.Size * SizeCoefficient
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next FormControl
    UF.Show
    Unload UF
End Sub
Function inputNumber(prompt As String, title As String, defValue As Variant) As Variant
    inputNumber = Application.InputBox(prompt, title, defValue, , , , , 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the coding help. It works great. I appreciate you taking the time.  (I apologize for taking so long to reply; death in the family.)